# Get the Value for the Key for iOS app consuming JSON

Tags: ios

I have a webservice (.NET) which returns JSON result. The iOS application consumes that web service and gets a response. Everything works but when I get the response it is inside the object d. Here is the response:

```
{"d":"{\"Name\":\"azamsharp\"}"}
```

Now, as you can imagine I need to access the value of the property "Name" which is "azamsharp". I followed another post which suggested the following approach:

```
 NSLog(@"%@",[responseDict valueForKeyPath:@"d.Name"]);
```

But this gave me the following error:

```
reason: '[<NSCFString 0x4cd6270> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Name.'
```

Any help on this issue is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no property "name" in that JSON object. Your JSON object has a single key, "d", whose value is a string, which happens to be the string representation of another JSON object.

You would have to do something like this:

```
NSString *innerString = [responseDict valueForKey:@"d"];
NSDictionary *innerObject = [innerString parseJSON]; // Or however you parse a JSON string
NSString *name = [innerObject valueForKey:@"Name"];
```

Comment: Just one more information: This "d" is native of .NET JSON class. It's because .NET use letter "d" to prevent some kind of injection when you need to parse it from javascript (don't ask me what kind of injection). So, yes, you will always have to parse twice.

Answer (score 2):

Another aproach would be:

```
NSString *innerString = [[responseDict valueForKey:@"d"] valueForKey@"Name"];
```

You would only need a single line.